# jQuery Validate not triggering

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have the following html and js, but it is not triggering the jquery.validate validation on text input field blur or form submit. If I add "required" attribute directly to the text input field, the default error message kicks in instead. Can anyone please help me figure out why the below does not work?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="test" action="test.html" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="txtName" />    
        <input type="submit" name="btnSubmit" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        ValidateForm();

    });

    function ValidateForm(){
        $.validator.unobtrusive.parse($("form"));

        $('#test').validate({
            rules: {
                "txtName": "required"
            },
            messages: {
                "txtName": "this name is required for sure!"
            },
            errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
                $(element).parent().append(error);
            },
            onfocusout: function (element) { this.element(element); }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
```

Why are you including the `unobtrusive` plugin?

You cannot simultaneously use the `unobstrusive` plugin while calling the `.validate()` method yourself.

Why?

Because the `unobtrusive` plugin automatically constructs and calls the `.validate()` method based on the HTML attributes.

Since the plugin only uses the first call to `.validate()` to initialize validation, it automatically ignores all subsequent calls.  So your call to `.validate()` is totally ignored.

> If i add "required" directly to the text input field, the default error message kicks in instead.

Because of the `unobtrusive` plugin, your call to `.validate()` is totally ignored by jQuery Validate.  That is why it only works when you put the `required` attribute within your `input` element.

Completely remove the `unobtrusive` plugin and it works fine:

**http://jsfiddle.net/ocx864nu/**